# adding a button in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to add a button to my fragment layout but it says that the method `findViewByid` cannot be resolved. I'm implementing it in the `onCreateView` method in the fragment. Why is it giving me this error?

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class extra extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra, container, false);

    }

}
```

Comment: it's because your class doesn't have a findByViewId method

Comment: check my solution @asdddd

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `View`. like,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra, container, false);
      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Button myButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use my code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra, container, false);
Button myButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class extra extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
            R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, null);

    Button myButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    return v;
}}
```

Use above code

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code :

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra, container, false);
        Button myButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
       return rootView;

    }
```